# C# Databind question

Tags: c#, web-applications, textbox, datasource

OK, So Im fairly new to Web apps, been doing Windows app for a while in VB but Im switching to C# for web apps. Ok so I have a textbox and I have a `SQLDataSource` called `SQLDataSource1`. How in the world do I bind the source to the textbox so when it loads it will populate it?

Can someone give me some examples?

Ive tried the following,

```
Label1.Text = SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.ToString();
```

But I get something other than the value of the SQLDataSource. I get this:  System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here on [Forum.ASP.Net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1286616.aspx)

Here is what has been said by Samu Zhang (Microsoft Online Community Support) :

It is hard to bind textbox to sqldatasource. We usually bind data controls such as FormView and GridView to sqldatasource and put one TextBox control in their Template . And you can invoke FindControl method of FormView to retrieve the textbox.

See my sample.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox box = FormView1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;

}

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="countryid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">


        <ItemTemplate>
            countryid:
            <asp:Label ID="countryidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("countryid") %>'></asp:Label><br />
            countryname:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("countryname") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
     </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [country]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="retrieve value" />
</form>
```

Comment: Couldn't I just on the Page Load use something like:  Textbox1.text = SqlDataScource1();  ??

Comment: @gabrielVa I don't think so, I think it wasn't designed to be used that way.

Comment: OK ill give this a try and see. You would think it would be just like a Win App with this.

Comment: @gabrielVa WinForms are by some ways much easier to design, IMHO :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is have your controls in a FormView or DetailsView, then set the DataSourceID of the FormView to the SqlDataSource and in your controls you bind them like so: asp:Label id=... Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MyFieldName") %>' />, then on your OnInit of the page you can call MyFormView.DataBind();